# In-App Purchases don't work in app thats Ready For Sale?

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect, iad

I have recently made an app called Lights: Out. It's status changed to "Ready For Sale" yesterday, July 21. When I downloaded it for myself, two things weren't working that should be.

1. The ads aren't loading
2. The in-app purchases won't show up

Both of these things work when I test it from testflight or Xcode. Is this just a matter of time before it works?

Thanks

Comment: Did you select IAP for app in In-App Purchases section? http://gyazo.com/712d9c77e0cb80400f89f656a0020903

Comment: Yes I believe so. Under the In-App Purchase section, it says "1 In App Purchase" and the status is approved.

Comment: Just guess, but I see "I test it from testflight or Xcode", so can you try log out AppStore account in Setting of device and try again.

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work. My brother also downloaded the game and can't buy IAPs etither

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Matter of time for iAd. It can take multiple days to be enabled.

In-app purchases are a separate issue. Make sure all your SKUs are set to "Ready for Sale".

Comment: Where can I check my SKUs? Is it in iTunes Connect?

Comment: Yes, iTunes Connect (under In-App Purchases). You probably (hopefully) "connected" them to your app when you submitted it for review. Make sure they're approved (Apple's side) and "Cleared for Sale" (the actual terminology, not "ready for sale", sorry). If any of them are not approved, that's a possible issue. If any are not "Cleared for Sale", you can change that by editing the IAP.

Comment: Under In App Purchases it shows the "Remove Ads" IAP. Its status is approved. When I got the Ready For Sale email, it also said this IAP was approved.

Comment: Ok, good. That's part one. Is the IAP "Cleared for Sale"? When you click on the IAP details in iTunes Connect, the current setting will appear above the assigned price tier ("Yes" or "No"). If "Yes", I suppose it's _possible_ that it's a timing thing though I haven't previously encountered that.

Comment: Yes, it is also cleared for sale. If i change the availability date to tomorrow, would it most likely show up tomorrow?

Comment: Is the current availability date in the future? If so, change it to today. If not, assume it's a timing thing. It _does_ take a little time for an app to propagate through all the pieces of the App Store, but I've never seen the IAPs themselves have this issue.

Comment: The existing date says "Now" and the end date "None" so I don't think thats a problem. It might just take time for the IAP to work like iAd

Comment: Certainly possible. The reason I differentiate is because there is a specific, separate process that the support team told me happens to enable the first version of an iAd app. I ran into the same multi-day delay that was separate from "does the app show up in the app store?" Give it 36 hours from the app-level Ready for Sale and if IAPs still aren't available, it will be time to talk to Apple. Your answers here suggest that everything you have control over is properly set.

Answer (score 0):

It took over 25 hours since my app changed to "Ready for Sale" yesterday, but it's "Approved" In-App-Purchase Items are still unavailable too.

I tested the function with TestFlight by adding a new binary, and the beta version can get the items without any errors. So the code itself seems OK, but the IAP server issue happens only on the version from AppStore.....

Comment: Thats the same for me. It works when I test it but not in the actual app from the App Store

Answer (score 0):

It appears that it was only a matter of time for both issues to be sorted out. The ads began working one day after the app was available on the app store and the IAPs took two days.